# how to add text boxes dynamically without losing values of previous textboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

i am using innerHTML to add text boxes dynamically. The code sample is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
  var i=0;
  function add()
  {
    var tag = "<input type='text' name='" + i + "' /> <br/>";
    document.getElementById("y").innerHTML += tag;
    i++;
  }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="x" value="Add" onclick="add();" />
  <div id="y"></div>
</body>

</html
```

Are there any ways to add text boxes dynamically without losing values of previous text box when a new text box is added?
Similar question has been posted, but there are no answers :(

What if I want to add textbox in this situation:

```
function add() {
   var element='<li class="ie7fix" style="width:620px;"><div class="m_elementwrapper" style="float:left;"><label class="fieldlabel" style="width:106px;float:left;padding-top:3px;" for="p1f4"><span><span class="pspan arial" style="text-align:right;font-size:14px;"><span class="ispan" xml:space="preserve"></span></span></span></label><div style="float:left;width:475px;" class="m_elementwrapper"><input type="text" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;width:244px;max-width:244px;" name="' + i + '"  class="fieldcontent"><div class="fielderror"></div></div></div><div style="clear:both;font-size:0;"></div></li>';
   document.getElementById("addskills").innerHTML += element;
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, through DOM Manipulation:

```
function add() {
    var tag = document.createElement('input'); // Create a `input` element,
    tag.setAttribute('type', 'text');          // Set it's `type` attribute,
    tag.setAttribute('name', i);               // Set it's `name` attribute,

    var br = document.createElement('br');     // Create a `br` element,

    var y = document.getElementById("y");      // "Get" the `y` element,
    y.appendChild(tag);                        // Append the input to `y`,
    y.appendChild(br);                         // Append the br to `y`.
    i++;
}
```

This doesn't trigger the browser's DOM parser like a `innerHTML` does, leaving everything intact.

(`innerHTML` forces the browser to re-parse the entire DOM, because anything could be added with `innerHTML`, so the browser can't predict anything, in contrast to adding a node to a element.)

Now, to add this:

```
<li class="ie7fix" style="width:620px;">
    <div class="m_elementwrapper" style="float:left;">
        <label class="fieldlabel" style="width:106px;float:left;padding-top:3px;" for="p1f4">
            <span>
                <span class="pspan arial" style="text-align:right;font-size:14px;">
                    <span class="ispan" xml:space="preserve">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </label>
        <div style="float:left;width:475px;" class="m_elementwrapper">
            <input type="text" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;width:244px;max-width:244px;" name="' + i + '"  class="fieldcontent">
            <div class="fielderror">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;font-size:0;">
    </div>
</li>
```

You'll need:

```
function add() {
    // Create elements
    var d1 = c('div'),  s1 = c('span'), ip = c('input'),
        d2 = c('div'),  s2 = c('span'), li = c('li'),
        d3 = c('div'),  s3 = c('span'), la = c('label'),
        d4 = c('div');
    // You can "chain" `appendChild`.
    // `li.appendChild(d1).appendChild(la);` is the same as `li.appendChild(d1); d1.appendChild(la);`
    li.appendChild(d1).appendChild(la).appendChild(s1).appendChild(s2).appendChild(s3);
    d1.appendChild(d2).appendChild(ip);
    d2.appendChild(d3);
    li.appendChild(d4);

    setAttributes(
        [li, d1, la, s2, s3, d2, ip, d3, d4],
        [
            {'class':"ie7fix",              'style':"width:620px;"  },
            {'class':"m_elementwrapper",    'style':"float:left;"   },
            {'class':"fieldlabel",          'style':"width:106px;float:left;padding-top:3px;", 'for':"p1f4" },
            {'class':"pspan arial",         'style':"text-align:right;font-size:14px;"  },
            {'class':"ispan",               'xml:space':"preserve"  },
            {'class':"m_elementwrapper",    'style':"float:left;width:475px;"   },
            {'class':"fieldcontent",        'type':"text",      'style':"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;width:244px;max-width:244px;", 'name':''+i},
            {'class':"fielderror"   },
            {'style':"clear:both;font-size:0;"  }
        ]
    );
    var br = document.createElement('br');     // Create a `br` element,
    var y = document.getElementById("y");      // "Get" the `y` element,
    y.appendChild(li);                         // Append the input to `y`,
    y.appendChild(br);                         // Append the br to `y`.
    i++;
}

// Apply a array of attributes objects {key:value,key:value} to a array of DOM elements.
function setAttributes(elements, attributes){
    var el = elements.length,
        al = attributes.length;
    if(el === al){
        for(var n = 0; n < el; n++){
            var e = elements[n],
                a = attributes[n];
            for(var key in a){
                e.setAttribute(key, a[key]);
            }
        }
    }else{
        console.error("Elements length " + el + " does not match Attributes length " + al);
    }
}

// Alias for shorter code.
function c(type){
    return document.createElement(type);
};
```

Comment: but wat if i want to add many tags in between <div id="y"> </div> for placing the textbox in correct place, i mean use css  for placing textbox.

Comment: It depends on where in the tags you want the new element to be placed. Can you edit your question with the additional info?

Comment: @bharath: Okay, that is still possible through DOM manipulation, but it's going to require (quite) a bit more code... Editing.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery library

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src='jquery.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
      var i=0;
      function add()
      {
        var tag = "<input type='text' name='" + i + "' /> <br/>";
        var div_content=$('#y').append(tag);
        i++;
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="button" id="x" value="Add" onclick="add();" />
   <div id="y"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's not really significant difference between using `.append()` and `.innerHTML +=`. Except that you have to load a external library.

Answer (score 1):

I've got round this before by reading all of the values into an array before replacing the innerHTML and then writing them back again afterwards. This way you can write whatever you like into the div. Following works on all browsers that I have tried:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
var i=0;
function add() {
if(i>0) {
    values=new Array();
    for(z=0;z<i;z++) {
        values.push(document.getElementById(z).value);
        }
    }
var tag = '<input type="text" name="' + i + '" id="' + i + '" /> <br/>';
document.getElementById("y").innerHTML += tag;
if(i>0) {
    for(z=0;z<i;z++) {
        document.getElementById(z).value=values[z];
    }
}
i++;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" id="x" value="Add" onclick="add();" />
<div id="y"></div>
</body>
</html>
```